# CSS label lose margin/padding

Tags: css, radio-button, label

I'm unable to lose padding and/or margin between 2 of my radiobutton's labels.

This is what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/putoz/6/edit

What I've tried so far:

- Forcing the width of the outer div
- Forcing margin-rigth/left and padding-right/left to 0px on both labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to make the labels block elements and float them:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qepoqano/1/edit)

```
label {  
    width: 32px;
    height: 29px;
    cursor: pointer;  
    position: relative;  

    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 29px;
}
```

You'll need to adjust the line height to keep the text in vertical centre.

---

Or, if that's impractical, just remove the white space from your markup:

**This:**

```
<input id="appointment-yes" type="radio" name="set-appointment" value="yes" />
<label class="yes-label" for="appointment-yes"></label>
<input id="appoinment-no" type="radio" name="set-appointment" value="no" />
<label class="no-label" for="appoinment-no"></label>
```

**Becomes:**

```
<input id="appointment-yes" type="radio" name="set-appointment" value="yes" /><label class="yes-label" for="appointment-yes"></label><input id="appoinment-no" type="radio" name="set-appointment" value="no" /><label class="no-label" for="appoinment-no"></label>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qepoqano/2/)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up adding margin-right: -3px; to my .yes-label which solved the problem.